# Mailgun binary attachement

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, mailgun

Ok, I try to send a simple *.xlsx file with mailgun using Python 3.4.

```
send_message(..., attachement=["/tmp/demo.xlsx"])
```

The code in send_message is given here:

```
def send_message(subject, text, fromAdr, to, attachement=None):

    files = list()
    if attachement:
        files.extend([("attachement", (os.path.basename(f), open(f, "b+r", encoding="utf-8"))) for f in attachement])


    print(files)
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v2/lobnek.com/messages",
        auth=("api", "key-2flidf93tp-u9moz95r8alhbl-pih1g9"),
        files = files,
        data={"from": fromAdr,
              "to": to,
              "subject": subject,
              "text": text}
    )
```

I get no error messages but the attachment is not sent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An xlsx file is a binary file, not a text file in UTF-8.

Your initial validation attempt would have  failed, too, if you had actually tried to read (far enough into) the file; but your code merely opens and closes it.

Comment: I see, I have switched to standard open(..., mode="b+r"). requests.post doesn't complain now but the email arrives without attachment